# Update data in parent when added in child in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I see a lot of posts for updating children when the parent is updated but I haven't found the opposite.

I have a parent component (MainComponent) fetching and storing data. The form to add data (FormNewSubItem ) is in a child component.

When I submit the form I add a subitem in an item and I want the array of items in main component to store the new data.

In MainComponent.jsx

```
storeItems(items) {
  // store items in db
}

retrieveItems() {
  // return items from db
}

render {
  return (
    <MainComponent>
     <ListItems items={this.retrieveItems()} />
    </MainComponent>
  )
}
```

In ListItems.jsx

```
render {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.items.map((item, idx) => <Item item={item} key={idx} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In Item.jsx

```
handleNewSubItem = (subItem) => {
  this.props.item.addSubItem(subItem);
  // how to update the 'fetchedItems' in MainComponent ?
}

render {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="title">{this.props.item.title}</div>
      <div className="content">
        <ListSubItems subitems={this.props.item.subitems}>
          <FormNewSubItem handleNewSubItem={thid.handleNewSubItem} />
        </ListSubItems>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So there are a few ways you can do this. A common way would to connect both components to the same set of data using a library like Redux.
But if you just want to do this in React, then you will need to define the function in the top level component and then pass it down as props to the child component.

So the `MainComponent.js` will have a function like

```
addSubItem = (item) => {
  // update the state here
}
```

Then you will pass it down as props to the component you want to use it in, so pass it to the `ListItems.js` component by

`<ListItems items={this.retieveItems()} addSubItem={addSubItem} />`

and then again to the `Item.js` component

`<Item item={item} key={idx} addSubItem={this.props.addSubItem}/>`

then in the Item component just call it with `this.props.addSubItem`

Because it is scoped to the top level component, when you call the function in the child components and pass it an item, it will update the state in the parent component

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Since I found this pattern is awful, I thought maybe there were a magical way to do it.

Comment: Using a library like Redux is a very common way to do this and avoids the problem of having to pass down heaps of functions like this. But Redux comes with its own set of problems as well haha. If you are interested in learning about and developing more with React, I would really recommend learning about Redux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using Context and the useContext hook if you don’t want to use redux for a simple app.